# pjsip default sound device doesn't capture and recieve audio

Tags: c++, debian, pjsip

I'm using pjsip to create simple app for outgoing calls. Here is my code:

```
#include <pjsua2.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace pj;

class MyAccount : public Account
{
public:
    virtual void onRegState(OnRegStateParam &prm)
    {
        AccountInfo ai = getInfo();
        std::cout << (ai.regIsActive ? "*** Register:" : "*** Unregister:")
                  << " code=" << prm.code << std::endl;
    }
};

class MyCall : public Call
{
public:
    AudioMediaPlayer player;

    MyCall(Account &acc, int call_id = PJSUA_INVALID_ID)
        : Call(acc, call_id)
    {
    }

    ~MyCall()
    {
    }

    virtual void onCallState(OnCallStateParam &params)
    {
        CallInfo callInfo = getInfo();
        std::cout << "******" << callInfo.stateText << "******" << "\n";
        if (callInfo.state == PJSIP_INV_STATE_CONFIRMED)
        {                          // call answered
            /*for(unsigned int i = 0; i < callInfo.media.size(); i++)
            {
                if(callInfo.media[i].type == PJMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO && getMedia(i))
                {
                    AudioMedia* audioMedia = (AudioMedia*)getMedia(i);
                    player.createPlayer("/home/srg/sample.wav", PJMEDIA_FILE_NO_LOOP);
                    player.startTransmit(*audioMedia);
                    break;
                }
            }*/
            
        }
        else if (callInfo.stateText == "DISCONNECTED")
        {
            exit(0);
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    Endpoint ep;
    ep.libCreate();
    EpConfig ep_cfg;
    ep.libInit(ep_cfg);
    TransportConfig tcfg;
    tcfg.port = 5060;
    try
    {
        ep.transportCreate(PJSIP_TRANSPORT_TLS, tcfg);
    }
    catch (Error &err)
    {
        std::cout << err.info() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    ep.libStart();
    std::cout << "*** PJSUA2 STARTED ***" << std::endl;

    pjmedia_aud_dev_index dev_idx;
    pj_status_t status;
    unsigned int dev_count = 32;
    pjmedia_aud_dev_info info[32];
    status = pjsua_enum_aud_devs(info, &dev_count);
    printf("Got %d audio devices\n", dev_count);
    for(dev_idx = 0; dev_idx < dev_count; dev_idx++)
    {
        printf("%d. %s\n", dev_idx, info[dev_idx].name);
    }

    AccountConfig acfg;
    acfg.idUri = "sip:mysipclient@sip.linphone.org";
    acfg.regConfig.registrarUri = "sip:sip.linphone.org";
    acfg.sipConfig.proxies = {"sip:sip.linphone.org;transport=tls"};
    AuthCredInfo cred("digest", "*", "mysipclient", 0, "password");
    acfg.sipConfig.authCreds.push_back(cred);

    MyAccount *acc = new MyAccount;
    acc->create(acfg);

    Call *call = new MyCall(*acc);
    CallOpParam prm(true); // Use default call settings
    call->makeCall("sip:sdbox@sip.linphone.org", prm);

    pj_thread_sleep(300000);
    delete acc;

    return 0;
}
```

The reciever can recieve the call and answer on it. However the calee can't hear audio from the caller and the caller can't hear the calle. When I'm trying to send data from wav file (commented part in the code) then the calle can hear this wav file. So it seems to me, that pjsip uses incorrect audio device as default. Here is an otput of the result of `pjsua_enum_aud_devs`:

```
13:17:58.664         os_core_unix.c !pjlib 2.13 for POSIX initialized
13:17:58.669         sip_endpoint.c  .Creating endpoint instance...
13:17:58.670                  pjlib  .select() I/O Queue created (0x5631f08a3420)
13:17:58.670         sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-msg-print" registered
13:17:58.670        sip_transport.c  .Transport manager created.
13:17:58.670           pjsua_core.c  .PJSUA state changed: NULL --> CREATED
13:17:58.671         sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-pjsua-log" registered
13:17:58.671         sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-tsx-layer" registered
13:17:58.671         sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-stateful-util" registered
13:17:58.671         sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-ua" registered
13:17:58.671         sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-100rel" registered
13:17:58.671         sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-pjsua" registered
13:17:58.672         sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-invite" registered
13:17:59.691             alsa_dev.c  ..ALSA driver found 32 devices
13:17:59.691             alsa_dev.c  ..ALSA initialized
13:17:59.691                  pjlib  ..select() I/O Queue created (0x5631f09354e8)
13:17:59.720         sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-evsub" registered
13:17:59.720         sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-presence" registered
13:17:59.720         sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-mwi" registered
13:17:59.720         sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-refer" registered
13:17:59.720         sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-pjsua-pres" registered
13:17:59.720         sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-pjsua-im" registered
13:17:59.721         sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-pjsua-options" registered
13:17:59.721           pjsua_core.c  .1 SIP worker threads created
13:17:59.721           pjsua_core.c  .pjsua version 2.13 for Linux-5.10.0.23/x86_64/glibc-2.31 initialized
13:17:59.721           pjsua_core.c  .PJSUA state changed: CREATED --> INIT
13:17:59.723             tlstp:5060  SIP TLS listener is ready for incoming connections at 192.168.1.79:5060
13:17:59.724           pjsua_core.c  PJSUA state changed: INIT --> STARTING
13:17:59.724         sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-unsolicited-mwi" registered
13:17:59.724           pjsua_core.c  .PJSUA state changed: STARTING --> RUNNING
*** PJSUA2 STARTED ***
Got 32 audio devices
0. default
1. lavrate
2. samplerate
3. speexrate
4. jack
5. oss
6. pulse
7. upmix
8. vdownmix
9. hw:CARD=Audio,DEV=0
10. hw:CARD=Audio,DEV=1
11. hw:CARD=Audio,DEV=2
12. plughw:CARD=Audio,DEV=0
13. plughw:CARD=Audio,DEV=1
14. plughw:CARD=Audio,DEV=2
15. sysdefault:CARD=Audio
16. hdmi:CARD=Audio,DEV=0
17. hdmi:CARD=Audio,DEV=1
18. hdmi:CARD=Audio,DEV=2
19. dmix:CARD=Audio,DEV=0
20. dmix:CARD=Audio,DEV=1
21. dmix:CARD=Audio,DEV=2
22. usbstream:CARD=Audio
23. hw:CARD=HEADSET,DEV=0
24. plughw:CARD=HEADSET,DEV=0
25. sysdefault:CARD=HEADSET
26. front:CARD=HEADSET,DEV=0
27. surround21:CARD=HEADSET,DEV=0
28. surround40:CARD=HEADSET,DEV=0
29. surround41:CARD=HEADSET,DEV=0
30. surround50:CARD=HEADSET,DEV=0
31. surround51:CARD=HEADSET,DEV=0
```

I use Debian 11. I wasn't able to configure builtin microphone so I use USB headphones both for input and output audio device. In `linphone` application everything works fine, but my app can't detect audio device correctly.
Is there a way to configure pjsip lib to use correct audio device?